# Powershell mount NFS with options

Tags: powershell, nfs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share on Windows with options, but am getting an error.

```
PS C:\Users\cclloyd> mount 10.0.40.1:/srv/Config H: -o nolock
New-PSDrive: Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'o' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -OutVariable -OutBuffer.
```

Why am I getting this error?  All the guides and tutorials show this command working just fine.  I have all NFS services installed in windows too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the guides and tutorials are talking about the `mount.exe` program, but what you're actually calling from PowerShell is a built-in *alias* to the `New-PSDrive` PowerShell cmdlet.

Run the program as `mount.exe` instead.

Alternatively, remove the alias using `Remove-Item -Path Alias:mount -ErrorAction Ignore` (e.g. you could put this in your PowerShell $profile script).

---

<sub>Microsoft doesn't really seem to *care* about the NFS client in Windows – it seems to be pretty much stuck in the "Windows 2000 and Interix" era. (There's no NFSv4 client support despite Windows having a NFSv4 server...) You will likely get better results by using SMBv3 if you can install Samba on your file server.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  Is it also possible to enable write access through powershell as well?  After I did your steps I didn't have write access.